# Swift - Label and Sprite position contrast

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am fairly new to Swift but along the way I noticed something strange. If I have a sprite and a label and enter the exact same position for each of them, they'll both have a different visual position. I am looking for someone to explain this as to better my understanding of Swift. 
Here's the output:

[image: screenshot]

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Test Game
//
//  Created by NioPullus on 9/7/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Owen Vnek. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var testSprite: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:                           "Spaceship")
    var testLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    func defineTestSprite(var #sprite: SKSpriteNode) -> SKSpriteNode {
        sprite.position.x = 100
        sprite.position.y = 100
        sprite.xScale = 0.3
        sprite.yScale = 0.3
        return sprite
    }

    func defineTestLabel(var #label: UILabel) -> UILabel {
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        label.text = "Test"
        return label
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(defineTestSprite(sprite: self.testSprite))
        self.view?.addSubview(defineTestLabel(label:self.testLabel))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:     UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit and SpriteKit use different coordinate systems, so you wouldn't necessarily expect a sprite with the same x/y values as a subview to appear in the same visual position.

You can use the SKView method [`convertPoint:toScene:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/convertPoint:toScene:) (and `convertPoint:fromScene:`) to convert between these coordinate spaces.

You can find out more information about the SpriteKit coordinate system [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW8), and the UIView coordinate system [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5). (As you can see, they are very different.)

Comment: Ok that helps a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NioPullus If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).